# chrome.tabs.sendMessage is typed void but returns value

Tags: typescript, google-chrome-extension, typescript-typings

I am making a chrome extension with compiled typescript, in which the popup script communicates with the content script using `chrome.tabs.sendMessage` :
**popup.ts** (simplified):

```
const tabs = await chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});

const {grades, recs} = chrome.tabs.sendMessage(
    tabs[0].id!, 
    {request: ['grades', 'recs']}
);
```

which gives the error: `Property 'grades' does not exist on type 'void'.ts(2339)`, however `grades` and `recs` are successfully assigned when using regular javascript.

the typing for chrome extensions has been downloaded from `npm i -D @types/chrome`, and indeed the return value is typed void. What would be the best way to avoid this error in typescript?

From my testings, the content script returns the desired value, still if you may find it useful, **content.ts** (simplified):

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(receiver);

function receiver(request:{request:string[] | string}, _sender, sendResponse) : true {
    (async () => {
        await Promise.resolve();

        let responseObj = {
            grades: {'a': [2, 3, 4]},
            recs: {'a': [1, 2]}
        }; // example response object

        sendResponse(responseObj);

    })();
    return true;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, if there is information missing, please leave a comment, thank you.

Comment: Use the **official** [chrome-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-types) package. If it doesn't help, either disable the checks for this line or write your own ts definition for sendMessage.

Comment: thats it, thank you, I read to use the install I used and didn't check